# Multi-tenant database - Database per tenant select table row from different database using view

Tags: mysql, database, view, multi-tenant

In Multi tenant database, I created database per tenant concept. but each database have same table name fields, Now i want to select the table in different database using view concept. The below example work for two database.

```
Create view SELECT 
    mydatabase1.Users.UserID
FROM 
   mydatabase1.Users
UNION
SELECT 
    mydatabase2.Users.UserID
FROM 
   mydatabase2.Users
```

But my scenarios I got a lot of databases. How will made the view or select query?

Comment: Add more UNION's...

Comment: but the database count is more than 1000's

Comment: Then use a different setup where the tenants share the same database. You can't have it both ways. They're separate databases, or they're not.